# Getting runScenario instead of scenario name in azure devops pipeline tests summary

Tags: azure, cucumber, azure-pipelines

I have cucumber framework in my organization and recently I created azure devops pipeline job, in tests summary it is not showing the scenarios name and it is just coming as 'runScenario'.

test summary in azure devops pipeline

[image]

what can be done to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Pass io.cucumber.java Scenario object reference in hooks that runs before and after the scenario